# How to turn an object into multiple key-value arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the variables in place and onclick function set up but I can't figure out how to turn this object into an array within an array. I'm trying to turn this

```
{"Wins":30,"Losses:"32}
```

into this:

```
[["Wins:",30]["Losses:",32]]
```

So I can append it to the data.addRows:

```
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Total: ');
        data.addRows([
          ['String', number],
          ['String', number],
        ]);
```

Comment: You're looking for [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Is there a specific reason the keys contain a colon?

Comment: @IsaacWIvins Are you sure, you don't mean `[["Wins:",30], ["Losses:",32]]`.  And why keep the `:` in `"Wins:"`?

Comment: when i console log `westTeamData = JSON.stringify({"Wins": westTeamWins, "Losses": westTeamLosses})` is shows up as `{"Wins":30,"Losses":32}` I'm trying to have the `westTeamData` variable converted to an array within an array so I can append it to `data.addRows()`. Using the `object.entries(westTeamData)` im unfortunately returning an array of each individual character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest releases of some browsers, you can use the new [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to do this:

(Credit to [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) for mentioning this first in the comments above.)

```js
var data = {
  "Wins": 30,
  "Losses": 32
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(data) //=> [ ['Wins', 30], ['Losses', 32] ]
)
```

However, you can also use the better-supported [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create your own `entries` function:

```js
var data = {
  "Wins": 30,
  "Losses": 32
}

function entries (object) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(function (k) { return [k, this[k]] }, data)
}

console.log(
  entries(data) //=> [ ['Wins', 30], ['Losses', 32] ]
)
```

Comment: If you credited Georg for his solution about `Object.entries()`, keep it up and credit me aswell, for `Object.keys()` solution.

Comment: @Kinduser I did not use your answer as inspiration. Pretty sure I was working on it when you posted yours; I came up with the answer independently.

Comment: Ah, fine then (:

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use following approach:

```js
var obj = {"Wins": 30, "Losses": 32};
    console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(v => [v + ':', obj[v]]));
```

Comment: And if the OP wants the `:` it would be `[v + ':',obj[v]]`

Comment: @epascarello It doesn't make any sense, I bet it's just a typo ;d Do you think that I should change it anyways?

Comment: @epascarello No need. We can be almost certain that the inclusion of those colons was a syntax mistake. If it wasn't a typo, there would have also been a colon *after* the closing quotation marks in the property keys.

Comment: @gyre Whatever, it's just nothing anyways. Lets give OP the solution he expects.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is great, but there is no IE support. Since you're using jQuery, you can se [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

```js
var myObj = {"Wins": 30,"Losses": 32};
var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
    return [[index, value]];
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**pure javascript**

```
var myObject={"Wins":30,"Losses":32};
var resultArray=[];
for(var key in myObject) {
    if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        resultArray.push([key,myObject[key]])
    }
}
console.log(resultArray)
```

> Result [["Wins", 30], ["Losses", 32]]

Answer (score 0):

Following code stores each pair in an array:

```
var obj = { 'Wins': 30, 'Losses': 32 };
var keyvalues = [];
for (var prop in obj) {
    keyvalues.push([prop, obj[prop]]);
}
```